# How to extract QP per macroblock or slice in HEVC?

Tags: hevc, h.265

How can I get QP value per macroblock or slice from a encoded frame (encode by hevc hardware encoder)? I have tried some hevc bitstream parser like hevcexbrowser https://github.com/virinext/hevcesbrowser but it doesn't have access to CTU or parse slice body.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode the bitstream using an open-source decoder, then modify that decoder to dump the information you need during its parsing. I'd recommend [Hevc test Model (HM)](https://vcgit.hhi.fraunhofer.de/jvet/HM)